# iPad image is getting cropped/resized while using image picker controller in objective c

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

When I use image picker to take photos using iPad camera , the photos are automatically getting resized/cropped while storing it.The same code is working fine with iPhone.Can anyone please help me to find out a solution for this. I am getting this in iOS 9.x.I need original images to be displayed.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please add the code you think that may be misbehaving

Comment: My problem is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309085/uiimagepickercontroller-on-ipad-with-ios9 .But how to fix it in objective c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue got resolved when I changed

```
UIImage * image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
```

to

```
UIImage * image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

in *didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo* method.